# How can I remove an allowed program from Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: security, ms-security-essentials

I was downloading a network packet sniffer when MSE properly warned me about it.  I responded to allow the program, since I didn't want it quarantined or deleted.

Now that I'm done with the sniffer utility and have deleted it from my system, I wanted to reset MSE's response to the file, but can not find an easy way of doing so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brute Force method:**  This works, but I would think there is an easier way...

Run command line as administrator:

```
C:>cd %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Security Essentials
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Essentials>MpCmdRun -RestoreDefaults
```

Within seconds, a notice appeared about the program in question.

Answer (score 4):

Simply launch `Microsoft Security Essentials`, go to the `Settings tab`, go down to `Excluded Processes` and you should see it there. Just highlight and delete!

[image]

Comment: It was not a process, it was a downloaded file that generated the alert

Comment: @Noah Look at the other two Excluded options - you should see it listed there.